# what is the "~/.dns" file?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I have a server hosted on hostgator, and I suddenly find that there's a `~/.dns` file created which simply has one line which is the domain of the site itself. What is this file and what is it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a standard file and has nothing to do with DNS but likely a file hostgator put on your server for management/administration purpose